# Input string was not in a correct format

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, types, type-conversion

I keep getting this exception (in the title) whenever I try to get the user id from the session (FormsAuthentication). Here's the code of the method:

```
    public User GetUserFromSession()
    {
        int userId = int.Parse(_httpContext.User.Identity.Name); //this line throws the exception
        IsNotNull(userId, "session user id");
        var user = _userService.GetUserById(userId);
        return user;
    }
```

When I first add the ID to the session, it is being added as a string. I tried using the `Convert.Int32` and `Convert.Int16` but I still got the same exception. How can I stop that from happening?

**UPDATE:**

Ok I debugged the project and checked the value of `_httpContext.User.Identity.Name` and it was actually an empty string! I do not understand why that is happening though... Here's how I login the user:

```
var authTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(
    1,
    user.Id.ToString(), //user id
    DateTime.Now,
    DateTime.Now.AddDays(30), // expiry
    dto.RememberMe, //true to remember
    "", //roles 
    "/"
    );

//encrypt the ticket and add it to a cookie
var cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName,
                            FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(authTicket));
Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

Shouldn't that do the job? Or am I missing something here...

**UPDATE 2:**

Check out this screenshot: http://i52.tinypic.com/2cnaw00.jpg
As you can see, the CurrentNotification property says there's an exception. Could that be real source of the problem?

P.S: The Helper class takes an HttpContext instance in its constructor, this is how I'm passing the current context: `x.For<HttpContext>().Use(HttpContext.Current);` (using StructureMap).

Comment: Is _httpContext.User.Identity.Name really an integer? Try to output it and see what it looks like.

Comment: @alex, I guess so. Because then if stop debugging and run the debugger again, the session would be there and I would be logged in normally.

Comment: @Kassem: Still, have you seen how the string looks? Maybe you have an letter that definitely should not be there...

Comment: Your string also may be empty and cause this error

Comment: @alex: I've update the question, check it out please and let me know if there's something wrong with what I've got.

Comment: In response to your updated question, are you actually creating the cookie and setting it from that FormsAuthenticationTicket? See the example here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthenticationticket.aspx

Comment: @elkdanger: I'm guessing something is being messed up with the httpContext... I'll update my question again, please check it out.

Comment: @elkdanger: Oh I think now I understand what you mean by your comment, I've updated the code again, was that what you wanted to see?

Comment: @Kassem I don't think the issue with CurrentNotification is relevant to your problem. Does your solution (temporarily) work if you use FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie() instead of creating the cookie yourself?

Comment: @elkdanger: Thank you!! Using FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie() solved the whole problem! I still do not understand why though... Mind explaining please? (do it in an answer so I could accept it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying using FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie() (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twk5762b.aspx) instead to see if that works, instead of creating the cookie yourself.

You mentioned this now works in your comment above, but I'm afraid I'm unsure why without seeing more context in your code sample. It could be something to do with the parameters you're passing to the FormsAuthenticationTicket constructor (check the sample at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthenticationticket.aspx - perhaps the forms cookie path parameter is wrong in your case?). Try using FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath as the last parameter, instead of "/" just to eliminate that possibility.

Answer (score 0):

You will get this exception if the string you are trying to parse to an integer is not a valid integer. For example if the username of the currently connected user is "john":

```
int userId = int.Parse("john");
```

you will get this exception.

Comment: I understand. But I do not know why I'm getting an empty string in the `_httpContext.User.Identity.Name`. Please check out the updates to the question to see how it all fits together. There has to be something there that is messing it up...

Answer (score 0):

Probably because httpContext.User.Identity.Name is a user name, not a user id.

Answer (score 0):

_httpContext.User.Identity.Name is probably not parsable as an integer in this case. You should debug or print out the Identity.Name property to make sure that it can be evaluated as an integer, or use int.TryParse() to evaluate the string to avoid the exception (depending on your requirements).

Answer (score 0):

Problem is the string you trying to parse is not a number.  See the documentation on the [Parse() method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/b3h1hf19%28v=VS.80%29.aspx).

> FormatException: s does not consist
>   solely of an optional negative sign
>   followed by a sequence of digits
>   ranging from 0 to 9.

You might want to use TryParse() instead.  That way a failure in parsing will return a false rather than create an exception.

Also is name really a integer or did you intend to use some other field that would contain an integer?

Answer (score 0):

The `FormatException` is raised by `int.Parse` when the `string` passed to it does contain a valid number.